# SQL UNION/JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, union

I'm trying to show the Student's First Name, Last Name, SID, Major, and Minor. As well as the Courses, CID's and Meeting Times for each student. The Bridge table is confusing me though. Idk whether to do a Union or Multi-Table Join or what. Please Help!

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to use both methods to create queries - what did you find out?

Comment: Yesss :) But it's the last problem haha. If that counts for anything
I tried making a UNION but it said that I needed to have an equal number of expressions in the target lists.

Comment: We're allowed to receive outside help.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, instead of answering your question directly I will provide you some tips.

You should really consider reviewing `UNION` and `JOINs`.

A UNION is used when you multiple queries that you want returned in the same dataset. They have  to have similar datatypes in each field and the same number of fields in each query. So for this particular question, does it make sense to use a `UNION`? Probably not, since you want the student and their course in a single row.

For this type of query you want a `JOIN`. There is a really helpful visual explanation of JOINs that is available online.  I suggest keep it handy to help you while you are studying SQL.

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Since you need the Student data and their courses info, the only way you can get the two is by using the `tblRegistration`. If you use this table, in your query you should get the results you are looking for.

Edit:

Since a commenter has pointed out that the second drawing is a `UNION` not a `JOIN`, which I disagree on here is an example to prove it.

A `UNION` as stated above combines two queries into a single result set. Here is a sqlfiddle with a [UNION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56400/1) demo:

[Fiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56400/1)

A FULL OUTER JOIN Specifies that a row from either the left or right table that does not meet the join condition is included in the result set, and output columns that correspond to the other table are set to `NULL`. This is in addition to all rows typically returned by the `INNER JOIN`.  Here is a sqlfiddle with a [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56400/2) demo:

[Fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56400/2)

As you can see the products from both queries are not the same so a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in the diagram is not a `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks :) But I don't know how to incorporate that bridge table

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Then I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @onedaywhen I disagree.  A FULL OUTER JOIN is not the same as a UNION, please see my edit with why.  Also this visual explanation was not written by me and has been referenced 100s of times here on SO just do a search for the article name.  I used it as an reference to show the difference.  If you think they are the same, please explain why.

Comment: @onedaywhen then I would take it up with Jeff Atwood the writer of the article. :)  If you search for Venn Diagram Full Outer join, it is the same in other articles. I just don't understand the downvote for referencing a popular article that shows the differences.

Comment: If he posted this answer to this question I would.

Comment: @onedaywhen the OP was asking if they should use a UNION/JOIN for the query, I explained a UNION does not give the results they would want to use a JOIN, then provided a helpful tool to review the JOINs.  I give you the point that a UNION/FULL OUTER JOIN have the same diagram visually but the logic is completely different and provides different results as shown in the sqlfiddles.

Comment: If you agree they "have the same diagram visually but the logic is completely different" then posting a link to the picture isn't useful and could be confusing. p.s. I should concede that a `FULL OUTER JOIN` is a kind of union, albeit one that does not conform to the usual requirement of union.

Comment: I guess we will agree to disagree, I feel that the diagram is useful because it also shows the logic for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStudent AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblRegistration AS r
  ON s.SID = r.SID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCourse AS c
  ON c.CID = r.CID
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be an inner join if anything?

Comment: @Kendall does a student always take at least one course? If yes, it can be an `INNER JOIN`. If there can be a student without courses associated, you should use `LEFT JOIN`, otherwise such students will not be in the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Syntax:

```
SELECT stu.FirstName, 
       stu.LastName, 
       stu.Major, 
       stu.Minor, 
       reg.SID, 
       cou.CID, 
       cou.MeetingTime
FROM 
      tblStudent as stu,
      tblRegistration as reg,
      tblCourse as cou
WHERE
      stu.SID(+) = reg.SID 
      and reg.CID = cou.CID
```